# Evaluate JSTL from a session bean

Tags: jsp, jstl, websphere

I've got a servlet providing a JSP and I'm trying to output custom tags from a string from my session bean. The custom tags get printed out without being evaluated. If I add my custom tags to JSP it works like a charm but I cannot dynamically add them from the session bean.
I've tried the outputting straight from the session bean:

```
<%= sessionBean.getTags() %>
```

and

```
<% out.print(sessionBean.getTags()); %>
```

I've tried creating a custom tag that accepts a string as it's attribute:

```
public class JSTLOut extends TagSupport {
   String value;
   public void setValue(String value) {
      this.value = value;
   }
   public int doStartTag() {
      try {
         JSPWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
         if (value != null) {
            out.print.(value);
         }
      catch(IOException ioe) {
         // TODO: handle
      }
      return(SKIP_BODY);
   }
}
```

I've tried using [Eval taglib](http://www.servletsuite.com/servlets/evaltag.htm)

This taglib caused a LinkageError, obviously not playing nice with websphere. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What's the functional requirement? What is the problem of which you think that this is the solution?

Comment: I need to dynamically add custom tags from my servlet logic into my JSP. The custom tags are being generated from backend data, however say I have a tag that evaluates to <h1>hello</h1> i'll get:

    <html><body><mytag:hello /></body></html>

Comment: Why don't you use a JSP template for this? Or are those tag declarations stored in HTML? Why?

Comment: My tag declarations are in a .tld, I don't think a template will work because I need the JSP to be completely generic as it can have many configurations. I will loose maintainability if I have 40 different templates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will be too tedious or not, but have you considered storing your custom tag names in a lookup database table?  You could then query the table for a particular custom tag name and insert whatever custom tag name into the dynamic JSP that needs to be returned from the servlet.